# Original Code Not Executing After Removing Javascript in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, jsp

I tried inserting some javascript into a jsp file on Eclipse. I added a scripts folder to the WebContent folder and added a helloWorld.js file and then added a script tag and did some input validation, which failed to work.

After removing all this failed javascript validation my original code no longer runs. I get a 500 error just trying to submit a parameter on the request. The parameter is null when I enter a number on the form. Any idea why? This is Eclipse.

I have deleted the javascript, the javascript file, and the scripts folder.

Yours Truly
(As Humanly Possible)
Cnight62

Comment: Did you also delete the reference to your JS file? Feel free to read on how to ask a good quesiton!

Comment: Thanks Aaron I will do some more exploring of the site before I ask any more questions. I did delete the reference to the JS file.